# Creating Jar Binding form Teamviewer

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio, teamviewer

currently I am trying to create an android app with xamarin and the teamviewer sdk.

I created the bindings from the tv-screensharing-sdk.jar and included the reference into my project.
After using the bindings I see only find ITVSessionCallback, ITVSessionCallbackInvoker, TVCreationError, TVSessionCode and TVSessionError in the Com.Teamviewer.Sdk.Screensharing.Api namespace.
The Teamviewer documentation shows far more elements in the namespace like TVSessionConfiguration.

What am I doing wrong?
What information do you need to understand the cause of the problem better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer in this blog post:
http://alejandroruizvarela.blogspot.de/2016/09/fix-for-xamarinandroid-binding-missing.html

basically you must add

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <JavaOptions>$(JavaOptions) -noverify </JavaOptions>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

to your .csproj file

edit: Further testing shows that it does not work with .aar files.